# Replacing fragment with fragment, nothing happens

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to go from fragment5 to fragment6 by clicking on imageview.

Here is my fragment5 xml

```
           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textfrag5label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="header" />



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textfrag5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="foo  "
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/forwardfrag5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textfrag5label"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="23dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="23dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_forward_black_24dp"
        android:onClick="clickEvent"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/show_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is my fragment5 class in which I have declared an Imageview called forward5. So, if I click on this Imageview I want the app to show fragment6's layout. But if I click on the Imageview, nothing happens. I don't know why. Can anyone help me please?

```
public class Fragment5 extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragmentdescrip5, container, false);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    ImageView forward5 = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.forwardfrag5);

    toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_keyboard_backspace_black_24dp);
    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getActivity().onBackPressed();

        } // this is for going back, e.g from fragment5 to fragment 4, this works
    });

forward5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.show_fragment, new Fragment6(), "NewFragmentTag");
        ft.commit();
    }
});



    return rootView;
}
```

}

Comment: you want fragment to replace itself?

Comment: No, when I'm in fragment5 , I want to go to fragment 6 by clicking on the imageview button which has a "forward symbol" as icon.

Comment: still your code does not look good. First you seem to attach onclicklistener to wholefragment instead of image view, then the transaction is also in that fragment. it should be moved out to parent container (i.e. parent activity) and the only thing that fragment5 should do on click is to tell parent to that was clicked

Comment: I see, I am new to "fragments" so therefore it is a bit difficult for me. Do you have any good example where I can understand better what you just told me ?

Answer (score -1):

that's because you set you container's height is 0dp,In fact you fragment6 had attached, but you can't see it.

you can modify the height of container

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/show_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"><!--modify 0dp to some you need-->

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work. I am still remaining in fragment5.